# Constantly switching dynamic data type performance in C#

Tags: c#, performance, dynamic, types

First post here, please be gentle.

Let's say we had this hypothetical use case where we needed a dynamic data type that was constantly switching between several types.

```
// Declare stuff
const string dataString = "String";
const double dataDouble = 2.0;
dynamic dynamicThing = dataString;
var w = new Stopwatch();

// Measure performance of switching types once
w.Start();
dynamicThing = dataDouble;
double dynamicDouble = dynamicThing;
dynamicThing = dataString;
string dynamicString = dynamicThing;
w.Stop();
```

In my development box, this particular example clocks at about 4936519 ticks. I've managed to pull off an implementation that does what I need in 25529 ticks. However, I believe that this might be still too slow.

Am I missing any other .NET Framework way of doing this that could potentially be faster than using dynamic?

Remember that it is a requirement to handle switching constantly, because if there was switching just once the DLR would just cache the dynamic value and it would be very fast indeed.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Could you also post the faster code? And, is your data always going to be value types and strings? If so, dynamic is serious overkill and you could just cast to/from object.

Comment: You might use `object` and casting instead of `dynamic`. Without seeing how you really intend to use this, it's hard to suggest a solution that meets your needs, or if you even need to worry about the performance at all (99% of the time you don't).

Comment: @PaulSasik I'm willing to post it to GitHub after I extensively test it, I'm kinda shy about it. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @TimS. I might just add the object and casting to compare. Thanks for the idea, how foolish of me to overlook that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that if using value types, the fastest way is to use object and cast.

```
object objectThing = dataString;
w.Restart();
objectThing = dataDouble;
double objectDouble = (double)objectThing;
objectThing = dataString;
string objectString = (string)objectThing;
w.Stop();
```

Only 14 ticks.